# Using the command, key code 125 using shift down, is not working

Tags: applescript

I am using OS X Yosemite, Adobe Acrobat XI (Pro) - Version 11 and AppleScript Editor - Version 2.7.

I am trying to press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>down arrow</kbd> keys by using the script below. However it fails, and just presses the <kbd>down arrow</kbd> key, not the <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>down arrow</kbd> keys. Note that the cursor is in Tag Panel when the keys are programmatically pressed.

`key code 125 using {shift down}` is working in most of the applications, but why not in Acrobat? Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
tell application id "com.adobe.Acrobat.Pro"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "com.adobe.Acrobat.Pro"
            delay 1
            key code 125 using {shift down}
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

First I have to say that I do not have nor use **Adobe Photoshop** on my Mac, however I can replicate this issue in another **Adobe** product.

When I'm faced with an issues such as this, i.e. when *code* works normally in every day use in most cases but not in a particular instance, I look for an alternate method to achieve the goal.

When the `key code` and or `keypress` *commands* of **System Events** fail to do as I wish, I turn to a third-party utility named [`cliclick`](https://www.bluem.net/en/projects/cliclick/), and use it with the `do shell script` *command*, e.g.:

```
do shell script "cliclick kd:shift kp:arrow-down ku:shift"
```

So the following lines of *code* would replace the *code* shown in your OP:

```
activate application id "com.adobe.Acrobat.Pro"
delay 1
do shell script "cliclick kd:shift kp:arrow-down ku:shift"
```

- Note that the *value* of the `delay` *command* may need to be adjusted for your system, and or additional `delay` *commands* may or may not be needed. Adjust *values* of and or add/remove the `delay` *commands* as appropriate.
- The *example* **AppleScript** *code* presented herein was tested and worked in another **Adobe** product to achieve the desired goal, however this is no guaranty it will work in all **Adobe** products. This post is just to demonstrate an alternate method which may be usable as a workaround for the issue you face using `key code 125 using {shift down}` with **Adobe Photoshop**.
- Note that I have placed the `cliclick` *command line executable* in a directory that is within the `PATH` passed to the `do shell script` *command*, `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. Either do the same or use the *fully qualified pathname* to the `cliclick` *command line executable* on your system.
- I am not affiliated in any manner with Cliclick and or Carsten Blüm the developer of this utility, and only use the utility for my own personal use.

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not employ any *error handling* and is meant only to show one of many ways to accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.